# What is the "?:" operator used for in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

Trying to understand this line of Groovy code:

```
return strat?.descriptor?.displayName ?: "null"
```

Is the `?:` a shorthand if/else? Does this mean if `strat?.descriptor?.displayName` is not null, print it, or else print `null` ?

I'm confused because there isn't anything between the `?` and `:` like I would normally expect in an if/else statement.

Comment: Why don't you read the groovy documentation? http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/core-operators.html#_elvis_operator

Comment: @JBNizet, pointing to particular operator does not make sense to me. OP might be starting with programming and not even know about elvis or ternary operator. It would be better do direct OP to groovy operators docs.

Comment: thanks, wasn't aware of elvis operator before

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Just to add some more insight, the "?:" operator is known as the binary operator or commonly referred to as the elvis operator. The following code examples all produce the same results where x evaluates to true according to [Groovy Truth](http://www.groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#the-groovy-truth)

```
// These three code snippets mean the same thing. 
// If x is true according to groovy truth return x else return y
x ?: y

x ? x : y  // Standard ternary operator.

if (x) {
  return x
} else {
  return y
}
```

Click here for more info on [Elvis Operator](http://www.groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_elvis_operator)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the "?:" operator will return the value to the left, if it is not null. Else, return the value to the right.

Comment: be aware, that elvis works with groovy truth.  it's not only `null`, but all falsey.  e.g. `"" ?: "empty" ===> empty`

Comment: "Yes, the "?:" operator will return the value to the left, if it is not null." - That is incorrect. There are non-null values for which the operator will return the value to the right (empty list, empty String, number zero, false, etc.).  The operator returns the value on the left if the value on the left evaluates to "true" per Groovy truth rules.  See http://www.groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#Groovy-Truth.

Answer (score 1):

The ? operator is the one you're asking about. That is the safe navigation operator. It is used to avoid null exception and return null value instead.

You can read more about it here:
https://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_safe_navigation_operator